# How to keep track on new cryptocurrencies

Tags: alternatives, currencies

Here is a situation: new cryptocurrencies appears with a huge speed and also most of them are just useless clones, there might be some interesting one with new ideas. I would like be know when they appears to read about the differences from previous one. Right now my only place to go is a [bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/) site to and hopelessly search in alternative currencies branch.

But this is not effective, and requires a lot of time. So the question: is there an easy way to get notified (something like subscribe to news and get email) when a new crypto was introduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently found a [resource](http://com-http.us) that seems to be very comprehensive. At the moment indexes 156 different cryptocurrencies and it seems to be updated quite often.

The main page has a sidebar titled "Latest Coins" that might be useful for what you need.

Each currency has a page with info and relevant links like a block explorer, homepage, etc... (See for example the page for [Protoshares](http://com-http.us/ccdir/pts/))

Answer (score 0):

Look at it from a business perspective. Start by polling the following.

1. http://coinmarketcap.com/
2. http://dustcoin.com/mining